# angular 2 patch value reactive forms returns undefined

Tags: forms, angular, typescript, subscribe, reactive

after this..

```
 ngOnInit() { 
this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
  let id = Number.parseInt(params['id']);
  console.log('getting person with id: ', id);
  this.peopleService
    .get(id)
    .subscribe(p => this.person = p);
});
```

}

why does

```
console.log(this.person);
```

return undefined?
 [code my code is based on this](https://github.com/Vintharas/angular2-step-by-step-06-consuming-real-data-with-http/blob/master/src/app/person-details/person-details.component.ts)
It all works fine when I use it in the html, for example

```
{{person.id}}
```

and it works fine in my component.ts when I pass the data to a Material dialog  using

```
data:this.activity
```

I've added

```
@input person:Person;
```

What do I need to do to be able to console.log(this.person) ?

The reason I'm asking is curiosity and also I need use patchValue on a reactive form and I get undefined if I add

```
 this.personForm
       // .patchValue({name:this.person.name});
```

I rewrote the subscribe line

```
         .subscribe((response) =>{
          this.person = response; 
          this.personForm
         .patchValue({name:this.person.name});              
          });
```

and it works but probably not the nicest way to do it?

Comment: Where is `console.log(this.person);` line?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an Observable/http/async call in angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055706/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-observable-http-async-call-in-angular2)

Comment: Not enough context to establish what is going on, try moving your logic into ngAfterViewInit() instead of ngOnInit(). Maybe your data is not ready during ngOnInit()

Comment: @echonax thanks that is pretty much it

Comment: @echonax I had it after `this.peopleService
    .get(id)
    .subscribe(p => this.person = p);`

Comment: @vtechmonkey if the issue is solved can you mark it as solved please: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250981/new-ui-encourages-askers-to-confirm-or-dispute-duplicate-votes

Comment: @echonax sure, where!?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250981/new-ui-encourages-askers-to-confirm-or-dispute-duplicate-votes

Comment: yeah I read that but the banner is gone

Comment: It's gone cuz you edited the question :-) it will reappear when another person also mark it as dupe